# How to implement a Visual Studio MEF extension providing a "navigation" combo box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I developed a small Visual Studio extension using MEF. The extension adds text formatting, intellisense and tooltips to a text file with a DSL.

Is there any way, using MEF, to add a combo box in the upper right corner that would hold "first level" constructs of the DSL, to allow easy navigation to where they are defined within the file? I'm thinking of something quite similar to what the default Visual Studio C# editor has in place to select classes (upper left corner) or methods/properties/etc within the class (upper right corner).

Since the extension already has formatting and intellisense, the code necessary to identify and tag the constructs I'd like to include in the combo, and their line number, is already done. I'd just need some pointers as to how to add the combo to the upper margin of the editor and make it move the cursor to a specific line upon selection changed.

Answer (score 1):

You're interested in the Type and Member Dropdown Bars, which (last I checked) are not exposed to MEF extensions. You'll need to do one of the following:

1. Create your own adaptor to the [`IVsDropdownBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivsdropdownbar.aspx) which you can use from MEF extensions.
2. Avoid the standard feature all-together and implement an [`IWpfTextViewMarginProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextviewmarginprovider.aspx) which creates margins in the same location, style, and function of the original ones.

If you use the second approach, keep in mind that it will differ from the standard feature. If you use the Window → Split command in Visual Studio for C# or another standard language, it will create a top and bottom pane that will share a single a single set of type & member bars. A custom [`IWpfTextViewMargin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextviewmargin.aspx) would be duplicated in this same scenario.

The dropdowns used in my [ANTLR Language Support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f) extension for Visual Studio 2010 uses the second approach, which it turned out was far from trivial but at least I was able to reuse the component I created for the other language extensions I released.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what @280Z28 said, I would advise against implementing an `IVsDropdownBar` and recommend using an `IWpfTextViewMarginProvider`. The margin provider route is a MEF extension the editor directly provides and allows you to control the loading of your margin via the editor's `TextViewRole` and `ContentType` attributes that you can put on your exported margin provider.

In order to move the caret to a given function location, you can use a variety of methods, such as those provided by the `IWpfTextView.Caret`. Make sure you call `EnsureVisible` on the caret after you move it to guarantee that the text view will scroll to the position you have moved the caret to.

Regarding the split window case that @280Z28 mentioned, you can always the methods of the `IPropertyOwner` and add a property to the property bag offered by the `ITextBuffer.Properties` to check for cases where you already have provided a margin for the buffer. By adding a tag to the property bag, you can check for the split case and return null in your margin provider to mimic the C# drop down bar behavior in split window cases. If you decide to utilize the property bag of the `ITextBuffer`, ensure you watch out for projection scenarios.